# Learning to write code for Stack Exchange maths questions?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, new-users, mathjax

I am new to Stack Exchange and I wish to know the methods, people use in this community.

For example, I saw many maths questions written in codes. Where can I learn to write those codes?

Comment: Beyond what I linked to you can visit the [help] and the [FAQ]. Also the site specific meta often have a collection of posts geared towards that specific community. Do note you're now on the Network-wide meta. On this site we govern policies and guidance that apply to all sites across the network.